# How to convert from .h264 to .ts using FFmpeg wrapper for C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ffmpeg, sharpffmpeg

### Context

I'm using [FFMpegCore](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore) in my .NET Core API project that receives a `.h264` file (sent in a binary format that is received and converted into a `byte array`) to be converted to a `.ts`.

I want to convert a `.h264` stream into a `.ts` output stream using FFmpeg.

### Current Approach

```
(...)

byte[] body;
using ( var ms = new MemoryStream() )
{
    await request.Body.CopyToAsync( ms ); // read sent .h264 data
    body = ms.ToArray();
}

var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

// FFMpegCore
await FFMpegArguments
                .FromPipeInput( new StreamPipeSource( new MemoryStream( body ) ) )
                .OutputToPipe( new StreamPipeSink( outputStream ), options => options
                .ForceFormat( VideoType.MpegTs ) )
                .ProcessAsynchronously();

// view converted ts file
await File.WriteAllBytesAsync( "output.ts", outputStream.ToArray() );

(...)
```

### Problem

I'm not getting a working `.ts` file. What I'm a doing wrong? Could you please give some hint or help me with this? Even if you have other FFmpeg wrappers that you consider more suitable for this problem.

### Notes:

- I don't have the physical location of the files since this will receive the content of the files over HTTP. So, I will only have the byte array meaning that I need to use the input stream to convert to another format.
- FFmpeg command used to test the conversion from `.h264` to `.ts` (using files): `ffmpeg -i file.h264 -an -vcodec copy -f mpegts output.ts`

Comment: What do you mean by not getting working .ts file? Corrupted? Not expected codecs? Doesn't open in video application?

Comment: The video doesn't execute. Do you know if the command that I used with FFmpegCore wrapper is correct? I think the problem could be related to the instruction of the FFmpegCore that I'm using. Maybe some missing argument or codec @Evk

Comment: I just tried to convert mp4 video (with h264 video + aac audio) using your code and resulting file seems to be fine (it's not corrupted and plays)

Comment: With the code that I shared? @Evk

Comment: Yes with exactly that code (except reading input from file, but also to the byte array as you do).

Comment: How may bytes are in your output file?  You need to set the position on the memory stream to zero after writing and before reading.  So you are missing : outputStream.Position = 0;

Comment: Apparently was missing the following argument: .WithVideoCodec( "h264" ) on FFMpegArguments instruction. Thank you @Evk. Should I update my question with this working code?

Comment: I've tried that but it wasn't the issue but you're right. thank you @jdweng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing the following argument: `.WithVideoCodec( "h264" )` on `FFMpegArguments`.

```
(...)

byte[] body;
using ( var ms = new MemoryStream() )
{
    await request.Body.CopyToAsync( ms ); // read sent .h264 data
    body = ms.ToArray();
}

var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

// FFMpegCore
await FFMpegArguments
                .FromPipeInput( new StreamPipeSource( new MemoryStream( body ) ) )
                .OutputToPipe( new StreamPipeSink( outputStream ), options => options
                .WithVideoCodec( "h264" ) // added this argument
                .ForceFormat( "mpegts" ) ) // or VideoType.MpegTs
                .ProcessAsynchronously();

// view converted ts file
await File.WriteAllBytesAsync( "output.ts", outputStream.ToArray() );

(...)
```